# Как сверстать круглый блок с иконками внутри?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сверстать такое расположение иконок?
Если приглядеться, там по окружности (белый фон с несколькими кругами) расположены кликабельные иконки...

У меня вообще нет идей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вариантов реализации несколько, посмотрите в сторону табов например. У активного, там тултип есть. Создайте сначала несколько круглых блоков и т.д.

Comment: @VladSpirin тут наверно вопрос не про табы а про то как расположить таким образом блоки по кругу ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а разве это по тому же принципу сделать нельзя? Если это что-то вроде навигации (кликаешь  на название логотипа и т.д.), если же нет и это просто статичные блоки или вообще это что-то вроде картинки, хм...., тогда да, вы правы. Круги нарисовать это ж не сложно... Я увидев эту картинку, понял что это что-то более объемное, надеюсь я не ошибся )

Comment: @VladSpirin круги то нарисовать делов мало а вот расположить их по кругу и при чём если их много ...уже геморой

Comment: @МаксимЛенский вы меня не совсем поняли. Я уже больше о их поведении говорю (в последствии), и когда вам пишу это подразумеваю. А если уж просто круги, так тут лучше SVG, но вижу что вы уже и сами добавили это. И я написал вроде вначале, что вариантов реализации несколько.

Comment: @VladSpirin про поведение если не ошибаюсь автор не спрашивал ... если кто то раньше не добавит вариант с svg я сделаю ... завтра, если честно вопрос не из лёгких и достоин Полезного вопроса ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавляю новый ответ, так как приложение почти полностью переписано и не знаю какое решение больше устроит автора.

Что сделано вновь:

- Все изменяемые параметры переведены в проценты для достижения полной
  адаптивности.
- Блок окружностей, который обеспечивает круглую основу иконки с тенью
  переведен в секцию `<defs>` для многократного использования с помощью
  команды `<use>`
- Упрощена формула фильтра, который размывает тень
- Убраны фиксированные значения `width`и `height` из шапки `SVG` для
  получения адаптивности
- svg код обернут в `<div>`, что позволит менять размеры `svg` блока,
  меняя проценты ширины и высоты родительского `<div>`.
- **Добавлены ссылки на каждую иконку**
- Иконки распределены по всей ширине svg блока

*Для настройки размера и интенсивности тени увеличивайте или уменьшайте радиусы двух окружностей относительно друг друга. Так же для этих целей, можно изменять атрибут `stdDeviation="4"` фильтра*

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  
   <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" width="130%" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/> 
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
    </filter>
  
    <g  id="icon" fill="#fff">
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="2.5%"  filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>
   <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="2.7%"  />  
     </g>  
</defs>   
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon" x="120px" y="120px" />
  <a xlink:href="https://yandex.ru/">
  <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Rbo.png" x="96px" y="96px" width="4%" height="4%" /> 
 </a>  
 

 <use xlink:href="#icon" x="1000px" y="120px"/> 
 <a xlink:href="https://yandex.ru/">
  <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Rbo.png" x="976px" y="96px" width="4%" height="4%" />  
   </a> 
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon" x="530" y="200"/> 
 <a xlink:href="https://codepen.io/">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEW1L.png" x="497px" y="165px" width="5.5%" height="5.5%" />   
 </a> 
 
  
  <use xlink:href="#icon" x="310" y="148"/> 
  <a xlink:href="https://jsfiddle.net/">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y06Su.png" x="280px" y="118px" width="5%" height="5%" /> 
 </a>   
 
   <use xlink:href="#icon" x="760" y="148"/> 
  <a xlink:href="https://jsfiddle.net/">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y06Su.png" x="730px" y="118px" width="5%" height="5%" /> 
 </a> 
 
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: реально круто! Спасибо большое! Переделал под свои иконки и вуаля!) Правда, разбираюсь, как размер кругов отрегулировать, а так очень классно!

Comment: @Safbek  благодарю, я ссылки добавил авансом, подумал всё равно спросишь :)  Размеры кругов регулируй, процентами радиусов. <circle> Смотри чтобы нижний круг был немного больше. Затем придется подредактировать координаты кругов и иконок

Comment: @Safbek когда будешь в следующий раз вопрос задавать, давай сразу всё - иконки, размеры блоков, короче, как можно больше сразу информации. Я например сразу бы сделал твои иконки и нужные размеры. Учти, пожалуйста это на будущее

Comment: спасибо за аванс тоже))Насчет иконок и т.д. Подумал, что это уже наглость. Обычно на таких ресурсах направляют и подсказывают, а дальше уж  сами. Но твои ответы очень полезны. Очень доходчиво и по полочкам. А вообще на блюдечке))

Answer (score 4):

### Решение SVG

- Для реализации тени используются две окружности, одна над другой.
- К нижней окружности применен фильтр Гаусса.  С помощью атрибутов
  этого фильтра можно тонко отрегулировать насыщенность и положение
  тени.  `stdDeviation="4"`   `dx="0" dy="2"`   Я сделал, как у автора
  вопроса. Если нужно что-то изменить во внешнем виде тени, меняйте эти
  атрибуты и радиусы окружностей.
- Иконки добавлены через тег `<image>` внутри svg файла.       *Это
  гарантирует, что иконка и окружность с тенью не разъедутся при
  изменении масштаба.*
- Я использовал для демонстрации 3 комплекта иконок+окружности.  Можно
  клонировать и позиционировать комплекты других иконок с помощью
  команды

`<use xlink:href="#icon" x="20" y="100"/>`

- Иконки бывают разного размера. В этой технике легко изменить х
  размеры с помощью процентов `<image>`

`<image xlink:href="Safari.png" x="90px" y="170px" width="15%" height="15%" />`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  
   <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" width="130%" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/> 
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   
   <g  id="icon">
 <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="30" fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>
   <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="35" fill="#FFFFFF" />  
     </g>  
   
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon" x="150" y="50"/>  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Rbo.png" x="75px" y="76px" width="12%" height="12%" /> 
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon" x="20" y="100"/>
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEW1L.png" x="90px" y="170px" width="15%" height="15%" />   
 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y06Su.png" x="220px" y="120px" width="15%" height="15%" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Век живи-век учись. Я в svg вообще не шарю.(

Comment: @Safbek Да не за что!  Я помню вас с темы про дизайнеров и верстальщиков. Что-нибудь изменилось?

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT Нет, если честно.И в плане svg, и в плане верстки в общем. Очень мало времени могу уделять . Так по крупицам. Хотелось бы сделать верстку основной работой, а не только хобби) Пока не могу никак получить реальный проект.  А вы я вижу спец по svg, приятно читать ваши развернутые ответы)

Comment: а скажите, расположение кругов и иконок вы вручную на глаз подбирали? Просто очень много времени уходит, это нормально? или  я что неправильно делаю

Comment: @Safbek Да, вручную, но у меня ушло не так много времени, больше занимает время придумать, как сделать.

Comment: там просто три иконки и всё ? я что то не вижу ни чего кроме трёх иконок

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а это дело можно адаптировать? Если изменять  значения в "viewBox="200 0 400 400" уменьшаются круги, но не сами изображения, да и в медиа запросах это не пропишешь..

Comment: @MaksimLensky, где именно? у Александра?Только три, остальные мне надо доделать))

Comment: @Safbek я подумаю и дам ответ

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется что нету определённого алгоритма как расположить эти элементы

Я показал только **одну часть** ибо направляю в нужное русло

Дальше по шагам ... один блок в нём потомки ...и по такому примеру и сколько нужно потомков ...

Нужное правило для этого : **transform:origin(x,y,z);** и правильное позиционирование

Но лучше конечно для этого применить svg

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  width: 330px;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 90px auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.items>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: 35%;
  transform-origin: 50% 230% 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.item2 {
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.item4 {
  background: orange;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item1">

  </div>
  <div class="item2">

  </div>
  <div class="item3">

  </div>
  <div class="item4">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я позже поэкспериментирую и выйду на связь.(Я к тому, что пока не отметил ваш ответ как решение) Надеюсь, ваш совет мне поможет!